# Is there a nicer / more generic way of solving the dynamic casting?

Tags: java, generics, java-stream

I've a problem, where I think there is a nicer solution, but I dont know how to implement it.

I want to map a Class e.g. from Test2Message to MappedMessage. my API offers only a wildcard capture  in the return method (here: MessageStream.getMessages() )

Now I want to parse the messages and transform them in a MappedMessage. Is there a nicer way to avoid the if / else Mapping in the `.map(Runner::transform)` ?

It would be cool if I just could implement a method with 
`MappedMessage transformWithCast(TestMessage testMessage)`

Let's assume the class DomainMessage and  MessageStream can't be adapted / changed - in my case they're part of a framework, where I cant change anything.

```
public class Runner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MessageStream messageStream = new MessageStream();
        messageStream.addMessage(new TestMessage());
        messageStream.addMessage(new Test2Message());

        List<MappedMessage> mappedMessages = messageStream.getMessages()
                .stream()
                .map(Runner::transform)
                // .map (Runner::transformWithCasr  how ?
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    /**
     * is there a more elegant solution for this?
     */
    private static MappedMessage transform(Object o) {
        if (o.getClass() == TestMessage.class) {
            return new MappedMessage("From TestMessage");
        }else if (o.getClass() == Test2Message.class) {
            return new MappedMessage("From Test2Message");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Is there a way , how to invoke this method from a Java stream map ?
     */
    private static MappedMessage transformWithCasr(TestMessage testMessage) {
        return new MappedMessage("From TestMessage");
    }



    static class DomainMessage {
        private String message;

        public DomainMessage(String message) {
            this.message = message;
        }
    }

    static class MessageStream {
        private List<DomainMessage> messages;

        public void addMessage(DomainMessage message) {
            this.messages.add(message);
        }

        public List<?> getMessages() {
            return this.messages;
        }
    }

    static class TestMessage extends DomainMessage {
        TestMessage() {
            super("Test Message");
        }
    }

    static class Test2Message extends DomainMessage {
        Test2Message() {
            super("Test 2 Message");
        }
    }

    static class MappedMessage {
        String value;

        MappedMessage(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `transform` does not compile, as there is no fallback `return` statement. Besides that, is the string to be returned by `transform` different to the one stored in `DomainMessage.message`? And why does `getMessages()` return `List<?>` instead of `List<DomainMessage>` which would make the cast unnecessary?

Comment: I've updated my question: 

"Let's assume the class DomainMessage and MessageStream can't be adapted / changed - in my case they're part of a framework, where I cant change anything."

Comment: `.map(TestMessage.class::cast).map(Runner::transformWithCasr)` or just using a lambda with an ordinary cast: `.map(o -> transformWithCasr((TestMessage)o))`

Comment: And what do I do in case of a Test2Message.class? Or later maybe even other ones?

Comment: If all you want to do, is to map from `Class` to `String`, do exactly that, maintain a `Map<Class<?>, String>`…

Comment: Hi, unfortunately I need a complex mapping, not only a String mapping.

Comment: Perhaps, you need something like [`ClassValue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/lang/ClassValue.html). Regardless of how clumsy or complicated your `computeValue` implementation will look like, it will be called only once per distinct `Class` and the result reused efficiently on subsequent `get` calls.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that you can achieve this by model deleguation and polymorphism, which is a better solution than checking the class.

Mapped message :

```
static abstract class DomainMessage {
    private String message;

    public DomainMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
    public abstract MappedMessage toMappedMessage();
}
```

Then, implement

```
static class TestMessage extends DomainMessage {
    TestMessage() {
        super("Test Message");
    }

    public MappedMessage toMappedMessage() {
       return new MappedMessage("Test Message");
    }
}
```

So, in your stream, you just have to call this method which is both implemented in every class that inherit from DomainMessage

```
List<MappedMessage> mappedMessages = messageStream.getMessages()
            .stream()
            .map (DomainMessage::toMappedMessage)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Hope this help :)

Comment: Hi yes, this is better, but the DomainMessage class is in my real project part of a framework I'm using, so I can't change it. That's why I need another solution.